# Property does not exist on this collection instance when fetching from related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I have this query which return data from one table :

```
$existData =Booking::where(function ($query)use($start, $end){
                                    $query->whereBetween('start', [
                                        $start, $end
                                    ])->orwhereBetween('end', [
                                        $start, $end]);
                                })->where('status','confirmed')->get();
```

this returns data but when i add relation to it

```
$existData =Booking::where(function ($query)use($start, $end){
                                        $query->whereBetween('start', [
                                            $start, $end
                                        ])->orwhereBetween('end', [
                                            $start, $end]);
                                    })->where('status','confirmed')->with(['bookingDetails'=> function ($q) use($data){
                                    $q->where('user_type',$data->type);
                      
                                }])->get();
```

It gives error :

> Property [user_type] does not exist on this collection instance.

but i have created relation in Booking model

```
public function bookingDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\BookingRoomDetails', 'o_id', 'id');
    }
```

> BookingDetailModel :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BookingRoomDetails extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

I want this whole query should only return data if outer query and inner query returns true eg.  `$q->where('user_type',$utype->type);` and the time range exist which is already working fine.

Any solution to resolve this issue

Comment: Cpuld you share the **BookingRoomDetails** modal code?

Comment: @ShabeerAhammed Updated the code can you please check

Comment: Change your code like this and have a look.

`$existData = Booking::with(['bookingDetails'=> function ($q) use ($data) {
        $q->where('user_type',$data->type);
    }])->where(function (Builder $query) use ($start, $end) {
        return $query->whereBetween('start', [ $start, $end ])
            ->orwhereBetween('end', [ $start, $end ]);
    })->where('status','confirmed')
    ->get();`

Comment: @ShabeerAhammed getting this error `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\IndexController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given`

Comment: Inset this above controller `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query code like:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$existData = Booking::with(['bookingDetails'=> function ($q) use ($data) {
    $q->where('user_type',$data->type);
}])->where(function (Builder $query) use ($start, $end) {
    return $query->whereBetween('start', [ $start, $end ])
        ->orwhereBetween('end', [ $start, $end ]);
})->where('status','confirmed')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks i tried this but getting same error `Property [user_type] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: Is the error getting from view? could you check the `$existData` getting data using dd()?